# Very low accuracy for random forest

Tags: python, statistics, regression, random-forest

I have some data that contains difficulty scores for tests plus some features. Example (the numbers are random, my real data has about 800 rows and 8 columns):

```
question    time_needed    media_existent   frequency_changed_answers      score
abc          3545             0               1.25                          0.79
dff          3574             0               2.80                          0.03
xyz          1123             0               4.50                          0.60
mno          7000             1               3.77                          1.00
pqr          4656             0               1.00                          0.99
stv          4367             0               2.73                          0.33
```

The score is between 0 and 1. The closer to 1, the easier the question. The frequency of changed answers is how many times the answers have been changed before submission (the student was undecided) divided by how many times the question was answered (some questions are more popular).

Just like in [this](https://mljar.com/blog/feature-importance-in-random-forest/) example, I applied the 3 methods (Random Forest, permutations, SHAP) to figure out which features are the most important. All 3 of them consider this frequency the most important, then the time, then whether the test contains media.

For random forest:

```
list_of_columns = ['time_needed','media_existent', 'frequency_changed_answers']
X = df_random_forest[list_of_columns]
target_column = 'score'
y = df_random_forest[target_column]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, 

test_size=0.25,random_state=12)
rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100)
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
rf.feature_importances_
```

But the following score is just `0.2932189613132453`

```
rf.score(X_test, y_test)
```

Also:

```
scores = cross_val_score(rf, X, y, cv=5)
print("%0.2f accuracy with a standard deviation of %0.2f" % (scores.mean(), scores.std()))
>>0.25 accuracy with a standard deviation of 0.05.
```

What would be the problem?

Comment: This isn't really an SO-relevant problem.  The code is clearly working, so you're probably better off posting on https://stats.stackexchange.com.  That said, an R2 of 0.29 doesn't seem bad given those features, so you may not be able to do much better.  Where did `time_needed` come in the permutation importance ranking?  Is it aggregated across students or in seconds (or both)?

Comment: Just reread the question and see that `time_needed` was the second-most important feature.  I'm wondering whether it's averaged, given the different popularity of the questions.

Comment: @Chris The time needed is in milliseconds and it's an average, i.e. the total time needed for each test divided by how often it was completed. It is the second most important in the permutation and a bit more important in the random forest, actually. Why do you think the R2 is not so bad, do you mean that the number of features is too small or that the features probably don't have much to do with those scores?

Comment: @Chris BTW the score for the train data is very high.

Comment: `time_needed` sounds good then.  0.29 doesn't sound too bad given that there must be a lot of other factors, e.g. are all students taught by the same teacher for each question?  That said, if this is out of sample, the interpretation is a bit different as R2 is a function of the residuals, which are by definition from fitting the model.  There's no guarantee that out-of-sample R2 is in [0, 1], for example.